# Using wild cards with find and ls

Tags: linux, unix, tcsh

The find command doesn't seem to search recursively when using the * wild card

I have a directory with several sub-directories inside it, many of which contain pdf's. There are no actual pdf's in the main directory, just in the sub-directories within it. I want to find all the pdf's without having to open all the directories.

```
find *.pdf
```

Shouldn't my code return all the pdfs in the sub-directories? I get 'No match'. Am I using the wild card correctly? I've also tried it like

*pdf

*.pdf*

*'.pdf'*

with no luck. Same results with ls. What am I not understanding?

Comment: `find /path/to/dir -name "*.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

please try with

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf'
```

you can place your path instead of `.`

```
find /path/to/working/dir  -type f -name '*.pdf'
```

Comment: This will still fail if you have any files in the current directory which match the wildcard. You can fix this by adding quotes: `find . -type f -name '*.pdf'`

Comment: thank you, I will keep this in mind for the next time. I am fixing my answer

Comment: I notice you have answered many questions which ended up being closed as duplicates. Perhaps you want to try searching for a duplicate before spending time on composing a reply. The [Stack Overflow `bash` tag info page](/tags/bash/info) has a long list of common FAQs for Unix shell scripting.